# What does get_property do in Django views?

Tags: python, django

This is a signup page for customers. I can't seem to find what `get_property` does here. It's not a Django method. Looks like it has something to do with SQL.

My questions are:

1. What does `get_property` do?
2. Are there any resources regarding that?

   ```
   @ensure_csrf_cookie
   @session_optional
   def signup(request,session):
       c = {}
       if session:
           user_model = session.get_property('user_model')
           role_id = user_model.get_property('UserRoleID')
           if role_id in ['3','4','5']:
               c['menu'] = 'customer'
               c['UserUsername'] = user_model.export_property('UserUsername')
       return render_page(request,'modules/signup.html',c,session)
   ```

Comment: What's the tutorial?

Comment: Actually it's from a project that I'm studying from

Comment: Well maybe `get_property` is defined in that project? Are there any 3rd party libraries involved? If it's not a Django or Python method then we can't really help you without more information

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Wasn't sure if it's a django method.  Will look into the 3rd party libraries!

Comment: You're right,  it's in a third party library.  Thanks again